# Which devices have 800x600 screen resolution?

Tags: device, screen-resolution, web-statistics

Which devices (or simulators??) have 800x600 screen resolution?

I can see in the Google Analytics of my own website that a significant percentage (3%) of devices have this resolution.  I can also see this at https://www.screenresolution.org/ (4%) and in the csv download from https://gs.statcounter.com/screen-resolution-stats/desktop/worldwide (1%).

Could this percentage be due to e-readers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

800x600 is a common default for virtual machines/server monitors/old computers/eReaders. Basically any computer that has a squarish screen (400x300)x2 is usually 800x600. Common defaults for virtual machines are 800x600. Feel free to add any others!

Answer (score 2):

I was seeing the same kind of strangeness with this low resolution in my analytics. Nearly every hit associated with that resolution was coming from one place: an AWS Datacenter.

800x600 looks to be the default resolution for bots, or at least monitoring bots from AWS.